# My App connected to firebase don't setup the recyclerView when you initialize the activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have really strange problem with my app, it's a TabLayout with 3 fragments the 1st and the 3rd has a RecyclerView which is filled with the Firebase Database, but you can't see the information until you click on the 1st and 3rd tab, I don't know if I'm explaining well, when you start the activity and you are in the 1st Fragment nothing is showed, you can go to the 2nd and then 1st and still nothing showed but once you go to the 3rd and then go back to the 1st the 1st and 3rd recyclerview are filled, which can be the problem, here is my code:

These are my 2 fragments:

```
public class FragGastos extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterDinero.OnItemClickListener{

private static final String TAG = "SDSADSDS";
private Button btAdd;
private FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private GastosService gastosService;
private ArrayList<Dinero> dineros;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdapterDinero adapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_gastos_layout, container, false);
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    gastosService = GastosService.getInstance(user.getDisplayName());
    dineros = gastosService.getDineros();
    adapter = new AdapterDinero(getContext());
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_Gastos);
    adapter.setDineros(dineros);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    btAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.bt_add_gasto);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetalleActivity.class);
    Log.w(TAG, "HA PETADO AQUI");
    intent.putExtra("objDinero", dineros.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);
}
}



public class FragIngresos extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btAdd;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private IngresosService ingresosService;
private ArrayList<Dinero> dineros;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdapterDinero adapter;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_ingresos_layout, container, false);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    ingresosService = IngresosService.getInstance(user.getDisplayName());
    dineros = ingresosService.getDineros();
    adapter = new AdapterDinero(getContext());
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvIngresos);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setDineros(dineros);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    btAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.bt_add_gasto);
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Here is the adapter which is the same for both fragments:

```
public class AdapterDinero extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDinero.DineroViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener
{
     void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

private ArrayList<Dinero> dineros;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener)
{
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}


public AdapterDinero(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public void setDineros(ArrayList<Dinero> dineros) {
    this.dineros = dineros;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DineroViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_dinero, viewGroup, false);
    return new DineroViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final DineroViewHolder dineroViewHolder, final int i) {
    Dinero dinero = dineros.get(i);
    dineroViewHolder.AsignarDatos(dinero);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(dineros != null){
        return dineros.size();
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public class DineroViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView tvTitulo, tvDinero;
    public DineroViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemDinero_titulo);
        tvDinero = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemDinero_Precio);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void AsignarDatos(Dinero dinero){
        String total = String.valueOf(dinero.getTotal())+ "€";
        tvDinero.setText(total);
        tvTitulo.setText(dinero.getNombre());
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( onItemClickListener != null ){
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(this.itemView, this.getAdapterPosition() );
        }
    }
}
```

}

And finally I have 2 classes to fill the fragments:

```
public class GastosService {

private ArrayList<Dinero> dineros;
public static GastosService gastosService;

public static GastosService getInstance(String username){
    if(gastosService == null){
        gastosService = new GastosService(username);
    }
    return  gastosService;
}

private GastosService(String userName){
    FirebaseRead firebaseOperation = new FirebaseRead();
    firebaseOperation.getGastos(userName, new FirebaseRead.GastosLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void gastosIsLoaded(ArrayList<Dinero> gastos) {
            dineros = gastos;
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<Dinero> getDineros() {
    return dineros;
}

public Dinero getDinero(int i){
    return dineros.get(i);
}
}


public class IngresosService {

private ArrayList<Dinero> dineros;
public static IngresosService ingresosService;

public static IngresosService getInstance(String username){
    if(ingresosService == null){
        ingresosService = new IngresosService(username);
    }
    return  ingresosService;
}

private IngresosService(String userName){
    FirebaseRead firebaseOperation = new FirebaseRead();
    firebaseOperation.getIngresos(userName, new FirebaseRead.IngresosIsLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void ingresosIsLoaded(ArrayList<Dinero> ingresos) {
            dineros = ingresos;
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<Dinero> getDineros() {
    return dineros;
}

public Dinero getDinero(int i){
    return dineros.get(i);
}
}
```

And here is the function of a class which gets the reading of the database:

```
public class FirebaseRead {
private static final String TAG1 = "Operacion de lectura";
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private ArrayList<Dinero> beneficio;
private ArrayList<Dinero> gastos;
float total;
public interface GastosLoaded{
    void gastosIsLoaded(ArrayList<Dinero> gastos);
}
public interface IngresosIsLoaded{
    void ingresosIsLoaded(ArrayList<Dinero> ingresos);

  public void getGastos(String user, GastosLoaded gLoaded ){
    gastos = new ArrayList<>();
    final GastosLoaded gastosLoaded = gLoaded;
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(user).child("Gastos");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gastos.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String nombreAux = ds.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                String descAux = ds.child("descripcion").getValue().toString();
                String fecha = ds.child("fecha").getValue().toString();
                int precioAux = Integer.parseInt(ds.child("total").getValue().toString());
                Dinero dinero = new Dinero(nombreAux, descAux,precioAux, fecha);
                dinero.setId(ds.getKey());
                gastos.add(dinero);
            }
            gastos = ordenaDinero(gastos);
            gastosLoaded.gastosIsLoaded(gastos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void getIngresos(String user, IngresosIsLoaded iLoaded){
    beneficio = new ArrayList<>();
    final IngresosIsLoaded ingresosIsLoaded = iLoaded;
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(user).child("Ingresos");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            beneficio.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String nombreAux = ds.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                String descAux = ds.child("descripcion").getValue().toString();
                String fecha = ds.child("fecha").getValue().toString();
                int precioAux = Integer.parseInt(ds.child("total").getValue().toString());
                Dinero dinero = new Dinero(nombreAux, descAux,precioAux, fecha);
                dinero.setId(ds.getKey());
                beneficio.add(dinero);
            }
            beneficio = ordenaDinero(beneficio);
            ingresosIsLoaded.ingresosIsLoaded(beneficio);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I know it's a lot of code but I have trying to find a solution a lot of time, and nothing wokrs, please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
dineros = ingresosService.getDineros();
adapter = new AdapterDinero(getContext());
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvIngresos);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); // after
adapter.setDineros(dineros); // 1st
```

Did you `notifyDataChange()` in your `AdapterDinero`?

Maybe we can see if this work first:

call `adapter.setDineros(dineros);` first

and then `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

remember to `notifyDataChange()` every time you update your content.

> Update:

The RecyclerView has no content usually because its dataSet is empty. I suggest put some log to see what happened.

Since you uploaded your adapter, I found this

```
public void setDineros(ArrayList<Dinero> dineros) {
  this.dineros = dineros; << not good.
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

There's a little misunderstanding about `notifyDataSetChanged()`, It means the **ORIGINAL** dataset(arrayList) has been changed.

Your adapter only remembers the reference to the first node of the original ArrayList, you passed a new DataSet in, but the original arrayList did not know anything.

The correct way is `arrayList.add()/remove()/clear()/addAll()` and then `notify()`, that's how we modify the ORIGINAL dataSet.

for example:

```
public void setDineros(ArrayList<Dinero> dineros) {
    this.dineros.clear()
    this.dineros.addAll(dineros)
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You should not replace whole arrayList because that new arrayList is not the original arrayList.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering, I edit my question because I just dont copied the adapter  class now it is in the question, I have setted the notifyDataChange on adpater and change the order of setDineros and setAdapter and still not work, I believe it can be a silly mistake of I fill the 1st tab recycler view in the 3rd and fill the 3rd in the 1st but can't find that mistake. Thanks anyway

Comment: found a little issue, give it a try? let me know if it works :)

Comment: Okey, thanks I have setted setDineros like you show in your example, but still not working, I believe I have found the problem but don't know how to solve it, Firebase is asynchronous so maybe at the beggining it returns an empty array, and then fill it but still don't know how to make some interfaces for the class GastosServices and IngresosServices

Comment: Go to my new question, I have the code there, thanks!